# Why is the height of my div tag being calculated as 0 in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css

I'm working on a webpage ([link text](http://twoblondesandsomebubbly.com)), but I'm having trouble with the height property in Google Chrome. If you view the page, you'll notice that there is no background color. This is because the #mainContent has a height of 0px. In Internet Explorer, this is not the case. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because the inner content is being floated. Parent elements do not take the height of floated children. Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `#mainContent` css.

Answer (score 8):

Everything inside of #mainContent is floating. Floats don't make their container resize. The easiest solution is to add a clear right before then end of #mainContent like so:

```
<div id="mainContent">
<!-- inner bars -->
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a "hacky" solution (I'm sure there are more "semantic" ways), but it's the easiest and one of the most used. +1

Comment: Absolutely right. I've never liked doing it because of the clutter but it's dead-easy and well supported.

Comment: This one worked as well, but adding overflow: hidden to the CSS meant I didn't have to modify each page individually. Which I liked a little better.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling it will be something to do with the contents of the #mainContent div not pushing out the container properly. You should be able to fix this a number of different ways, such as using a clearing div.

Add the following css:

```
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}
```

And add a div with the clearfix class before closing the maincontent div:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <div id="rightSide">
     ...
    </div>
    <div id="content">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"/>
</div>
```

This should remind the browser to force open the mainContent div to fit its contents.

Answer (score 2):

Haha, this will be a hard question for you to check as answered because there are a variety of ways to clear floats. (You can also try floating #mainContent as well)

Here's the wonderful [quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).

Answer (score -2):

try explicitly defining the default

height:auto;